# Improper storage of token? Problems with file parsing

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, token

I'm working on a project where I need to sort some data from a file. The file is a long list of strings separated by a "tab space"( I think the file is delimited I'm not sure though). Here is a sample of one line of the file:

2986043 Pic de Font Blanca  Pic de Font Blanca  Pic de Font Blanca,Pic du Port  42.64991    1.53335 T   PK  AD

The two doubles in the middle(e/g: 42.64991 & 1.5335), are what I am concerned with as I'm going to store them and use them for sorting later. This is just a prototype using an array of the first 1000 lines of input, but actual size of file is something in the millions of lines. The actual data structure will be a linked list of some kind(I think? not sure what suits this kind of work best)

here is a set of loops where I am tokenizing the string from the file pointer, and trying to copy over the string to the array of pointers I have set up:

```
  int curr_line=0;
  int longlat;
  char* coord[1000][2];

  /* clock starts to time process
   * this pair of loops works through each line of the file, token by token
   *
   */
  start = clock();
   while(fgets(duff, 512, (FILE*)fp) !=NULL)
   {
      int coordFlag=0;
      //char* token=strtok(duff, " ");
      char* token=strtok(duff, " \t");
      while(token)
      {
        if(verify(token))
        {
            //printf("tok: %s\n", token);
            coordFlag++;
            if(coordFlag==1)
            {
                printf("%s||", token);
                strcpy(coord[curr_line][0], token);

            }
            if(coordFlag==2)
            {
                printf("%s\n", token);
                strcpy(coord[curr_line][1], token);

            }
        }
        //printf("tok: %s\n", token);

        token=strtok(NULL, " \t");


      }
      curr_line++;
      if(curr_line==1000) break;

   }
```

currently, I encounter a runtime error where the program crashes as it tries to store the first string. I believe I am incorrectly using the array, and/or, the char pointers for both the string, and the token.

My main goal is to parse the line of strings, which are separated by both whitespace and a delimited tab character, and grab the two strings in the middle, which are longitude and latitude, and store them in an array.

As a followup question, how could this storage be done as doubles. As in, can I parse the token, then crate a blank double variable, make a copy of the parsed token and store it as a double with typecasting, or some more efficient strategy?

Comment: @bmm6o But it shouldn't be supposed to do so according to rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using pointers which are not initialized and meaningless to store the tokens and that is very bad.

Allocate buffer for storeing tokens before copying the strings.

```
if(coordFlag==1)
{
    printf("%s||", token);
    coord[curr_line][0] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1); // add this line
    strcpy(coord[curr_line][0], token);

}
if(coordFlag==2)
{
    printf("%s\n", token);
    coord[curr_line][1] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1); // add this line
    strcpy(coord[curr_line][1], token);

}
```

Notes:

- Don't forget `+1` for terminating null-characters.
- Adding some code to check if `malloc()` was successful and handle errors will make this code better.